# How to set up a timer in Swift

Tags: swift, timer, nsdate

I'm trying to figure out the best way to keep track of time for a timer I've made. I want the timer to work while the app isn't open too.

I can say what I'm thinking in psuedo code, but I don't know enough Swift to make it happen. When the startStopButton is pressed, I'd probably want to set an NSDate. Then, every second, I'd want a new NSDate to be compared to the original to figure out how many seconds had passed. That way, if the user leaves the app and comes back, it just checks the original time stamp and compares it to the present. Then, I'd put that number of seconds into a variable that I have already set up to manipulate the way I want it. Here's what I have so far:

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var second = 00.0


    func timerResults() {

    second += 1        


    let secondInIntForm = Int(second)

    let (h,m,s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(secondInIntForm)

}

    @IBAction func startStopButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    date = NSDate()

    moneyEverySecond = (people*wage)/3600

    if updatingSymbol.hidden == true { //Start the timer
        sender.setTitle("STOP", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        updatingSymbol.hidden = false

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("timerResults"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    } else { //Stop the timer
        sender.setTitle("START", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        updatingSymbol.hidden = true
        //***stop the timer
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

If anyone can help, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the timer's start time through the `userInfo` argument:

```
@IBAction func startStopButton(sender : AnyObject) {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerResults(_:)) , userInfo: NSDate(), repeats: true)
}

func timerResults(timer: NSTimer) {
    let timerStartDate = timer.userInfo as! NSDate
    let seconds = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(timerStartDate))
    print(seconds)
}
```

(I removed some parts of your functions because they are not relevant to the question)